# Exclude dynamic content using Elementor from cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, elementor

While using Wordpress and a cache plugin such as W3 total cache / wprocket / siteground optimizer, Is it possible to prevent an Elementor dynamic content being stored in cache?

https://elementor.com/help/dynamic-content/

I tried everything with no results. It only works if I exclude the whole page from cache